# ORDER BY DECODE: Decode won't reorder the days like I want it to

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, decode

I've got an assignment where I need to return a certain report and then order it by the day, but I need Monday to be day #1 (by default, Sunday is day #1 in SQL). Here's my code for the report and the output:

[report without order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV5q8.png)
[output without order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhvRu.png)

I then add an order by decode, which runs and looks correct, but it doesn't order the days properly:

[report with order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJaKJ.png)
[output with order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp23e.png)

I don't know what is going wrong, so if someone could help I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Please include code and sample data as text, not images. Not everyone can open image links, and they can't be copied and pasted into code editors.

Comment: *by default, Sunday is day #1 in SQL* - [Monday and Saturday want a word](http://chartsbin.com/view/41671).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correct with the *default day of the week* in Oracle. It is not always Sunday, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A)  of the format `D` clearly states

> Day of week (1-7). This element depends on the NLS territory of the session.

So what you need is only to set the in your session the `NLS_TERRITORY` to some country where the week starts with a Monday and you are done.

Maybe your setting is already so if you got this requirement, simple check with

```
select * from nls_session_parameters
where parameter like 'NLS_TERRITORY';
```

If not set a propper teritory for example with following statement

```
 alter session set nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';
```

Now you can order on the *day of the week* `to_char(hire_date, 'd')`

Example

```
select last_name, 
to_char(hire_date, 'DD-MON-RR') "HIRE_DAY",
to_char(hire_date, 'DAY') "DAY",
to_char(hire_date, 'd') day_no
from emp 
order by to_char(hire_date, 'd');

LAST_NAME    HIRE_DAY           DAY                                  D
------------ ------------------ ------------------------------------ -
Mr.Monday    01-MAR-21          MONDAY                               1
Mr.Tuesday   02-MAR-21          TUESDAY                              2
Mr.Wednesday 03-MAR-21          WEDNESDAY                            3
Mr.Thursday  04-MAR-21          THURSDAY                             4
Mr.Friday    05-MAR-21          FRIDAY                               5
Mr.Saturday  06-MAR-21          SATURDAY                             6
Mr.Sunday    07-MAR-21          SUNDAY                               7
```

Using *day names* for ordering is not always considered a best practice, because it makes you `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` dependent.

If you want a *complete independent* solution then use the `IW` *trick*. The *calendar week* is `ISO`so it works overall.

```
 order by 1 + TRUNC (hire_date) - TRUNC (hire_date, 'IW')
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I must be doing something else wrong because we haven't gotten anywhere near this deep into SQL yet. Not sure that my professor will accept this solution because it's not what we've learned so far, but I'll try anyway.

Comment: @coryriegel98 - "we haven't gotten anywhere near this deep..." Did you learn the `trim()` function? Even if you didn't, a simple Google search would show you what it does: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm What I suggested is much more basic than what MB shows in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`"DAY"` is returned with blank padding (ask Oracle why they chose a fixed-length string return). Use `trim("DAY")` instead, that should work. There are simpler ways too, but let's do it your way. :-)

Comment: You can also change your format model to use `fm`, e.g. `to_char(hire_date, 'fmDAY') "DAY"`

Comment: @kfinity - that will change the data in the output, not just the order. Perhaps the OP is fine with that, but he only asked about changing the order.

Comment: Turns out my code was fine, just needed to change the format mode to 'fmDAY' instead of 'DAY', thank you!

Comment: @kfinity if you don't mind, could you briefly explain the difference between 'DAY' and 'fmDAY'? Both of them return the day name that corresponds with the date provided, but obviously 'fmDAY' changed the data type, and I'm not sure why

Comment: @coryriegel98 The [FM modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA) changes the "fill mode" to remove the padding spaces at the end of each word.